# pass parameters to remote machine

Tags: bash, parameters, host

I would like to be able to pass parameters to remote machine.
In this script I wanted to chmod some files on remote destination machines based on the permissions, that I find on the same files in the source machine.

It works for me if the destination machine is the same machine on which i am running the script (chmod $perm $path  part of the code works). 
If I try to chmod files on the remote machine, it doesn't work (ssh root@"${destnode}" chmod $perm $path).

There is another problem. This script can't handle spaces in the names of the files/folders. Can anyone help me fix that ?

```
#!/bin/bash
sourcenode=$1
destnode=$2
path1=/root/test
tmp=/tmp/file-list

ssh root@"${sourcenode}" "find ${path1} -exec stat -c '%a %n' {} \; " > $tmp
cat $tmp | ssh root@"${destnode}" 'cat - > /tmp/file-list '
ssh root@"${destnode}"  cat $tmp |
while read perm path
do
    #ssh root@"${destnode}" chmod $perm $path
    chmod $perm $path
done
```

Comment: The answer to "handl[ing] spaces" is to quote your variables when you use them. You do that for `"${destnode}"` already. What happens when you run the `ssh` version of the command? Do you get an error?

Comment: The trick with quotes worked on names with spaces :). thanks. No. I don't get any error. It seems, like the variables ( $perm and $path) become empty, when I try to pass them to remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you try to run bash code directly through a ssh. You do not need to copy the file-list to the destination as you have all the info you need on the host running the script.

Regarding the filename spaces issue I worked around it with sed, substituting the space between the permission and the file with ':' and then setting the appropriate IFS (field separator characters) within the while loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
sourcenode=$1
destnode=$2

path1=/root/test
tmp=/tmp/file-list

ssh root@$sourcenode \
        "find $path1 -exec stat -c '%a %n' {} \; | sed -e 's/^\([0-9]*\) \(.*\)$/\1:\2/'" > $tmp
while IFS=$':' read perm path; do
    ssh root@$destnode chmod $perm $path
done < $tmp
```

Comment: It doesn't work olopopo. Still the script can't pass the parameters to remote machine.

Comment: `:` is a legal character in file names. That makes it a bad choice for a delimiter. This is why GNU find has `-print0`. You are absolutely right about not sending the file to `${destnode}` though that is entirely pointless and costly.